# How to force wrap MATLAB code

Tags: code, matlab, wrap

I'm including a MATLAB script as an appendix in a report I'm writing, I'm using mcode to import it, but some of the lines are longer than the width of my paper.
In my master document I have:

```
\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
body
\begin{appendices}
\appendix
\onecolumn
\small
\input{appendices.tex}
\end{appendices}
```

My document is two column, but in the appendices.tex that I'm including I have the following:

```
\newpage
\section{MATLAB FBA Script, quoted verbatim}
\lstinputlisting{MY_FILE_PATH.m}
\label{FBAscript}
```

Unfortunately, some of the lines of my code have the ends missing, especially when I've defined long arrays.

Could you please advise me on how to force wrap the text, while maintaining the correct line numbering?

The part causing me the most trouble are these long matlab lists:

```
%biomassRxns = {'Biomass_BT_v2'};
%long including LTA/LPDC
%biomassRxns = {'EX_cpd00002(b)','EX_cpd00006(b)','EX_cpd00005(b)','EX_cpd00010(b)','EX_cpd00003(b)','EX_cpd00012(b)','EX_cpd00018(b)','EX_cpd00001(b)','EX_cpd00046(b)','EX_cpd00096(b)','EX_cpd00254(b)','EX_cpd00052(b)','EX_cpd00038(b)','EX_cpd00031(b)','EX_cpd11493(b)','EX_cpd00126(b)','EX_cpd10516(b)','EX_cpd00205(b)','EX_cpd11463(b)','EX_cpd15499(b)','EX_cpd00063(b)','EX_cpd11462(b)','EX_cpd11461(b)','EX_cpd15664(b)','EX_cpd00201(b)','LPDC_cpd15697(c)','LPDC_cpd15729(c)','LPDC_cpd15742(c)','LPDC_cpd15700(c)','LPDC_cpd15741(c)','LPDC_cpd15732(c)','LPDC_cpd15724(c)','LPDC_cpd15533(c)','LPDC_cpd15695(c)','LPDC_cpd15738(c)','LPDC_cpd15745(c)','LPDC_cpd15736(c)','LPDC_cpd15727(c)','LPDC_cpd15799(c)','LPDC_cpd15743(c)','LPDC_cpd15696(c)','LPDC_cpd15740(c)','LPDC_cpd15699(c)','LPDC_cpd15731(c)','LPDC_cpd15536(c)','LPDC_cpd15792(c)','LPDC_cpd15737(c)','LPDC_cpd15728(c)','LPDC_cpd15744(c)','LPDC_cpd15726(c)','LPDC_cpd15798(c)','LPDC_cpd15723(c)','LPDC_cpd15795(c)','LPDC_cpd15739(c)','LPDC_cpd15730(c)','LPDC_cpd15698(c)','LPDC_cpd15722(c)','LPDC_cpd15794(c)','LPDC_cpd15735(c)','LPDC_cpd15538(c)','LPDC_cpd15791(c)','LPDC_cpd15725(c)','LPDC_cpd15797(c)','LPDC_cpd15531(c)','LPDC_cpd15734(c)','LPDC_cpd15733(c)','LPDC_cpd15540(c)','LPDC_cpd15793(c)','LPDC_cpd15529(c)','LPDC_cpd15712(c)','LPDC_cpd15782(c)','LPDC_cpd15714(c)','LPDC_cpd15788(c)','LPDC_cpd15790(c)','LPDC_cpd15789(c)','LPDC_cpd15710(c)','LPDC_cpd15786(c)','LPDC_cpd15713(c)','LPDC_cpd15707(c)','LPDC_cpd15715(c)','LPDC_cpd15711(c)','LPDC_cpd15787(c)','LPDC_cpd15783(c)','LPDC_cpd15709(c)','LPDC_cpd15784(c)','LPDC_cpd15708(c)','LPDC_cpd15785(c)','LTA_cpd15747(c)','LTA_cpd15750(c)','LTA_cpd15753(c)','LTA_cpd15749(c)','LTA_cpd15754(c)','LTA_cpd15752(c)','LTA_cpd15748(c)','LTA_cpd15751(c)','LTA_cpd15746(c)','LTA_cpd15759(c)','LTA_cpd15775(c)','LTA_cpd15767(c)','LTA_cpd15768(c)','LTA_cpd15766(c)','LTA_cpd15758(c)','LTA_cpd15757(c)','LTA_cpd15777(c)','LTA_cpd15776(c)','LTA_cpd15769(c)','LTA_cpd15761(c)','LTA_cpd15762(c)','LTA_cpd15756(c)','LTA_cpd15755(c)','LTA_cpd15764(c)','LTA_cpd15771(c)','LTA_cpd15760(c)','LTA_cpd15779(c)','LTA_cpd15774(c)','LTA_cpd15781(c)','LTA_cpd15763(c)','LTA_cpd15772(c)','LTA_cpd15770(c)','LTA_cpd15765(c)','LTA_cpd15773(c)','LTA_cpd15780(c)','LTA_cpd15778(c)'};
%long reaction list
%biomassRxns = {'EX_cpd00002(b)','EX_cpd00006(b)','EX_cpd00005(b)','EX_cpd00010(b)','EX_cpd00003(b)','EX_cpd00012(b)','EX_cpd00018(b)','EX_cpd00001(b)','EX_cpd00046(b)','EX_cpd00096(b)','EX_cpd00254(b)','EX_cpd00052(b)','EX_cpd00038(b)','EX_cpd00031(b)','EX_cpd11493(b)','EX_cpd00126(b)','EX_cpd10516(b)','EX_cpd00205(b)','EX_cpd11463(b)','EX_cpd15499(b)','EX_cpd00063(b)','EX_cpd11462(b)','EX_cpd11461(b)','EX_cpd15664(b)','EX_cpd00201(b)','EX_cpd15800(b)','EX_cpd15670(b)'};
%long less teichoic acid composition
biomassRxns = {'EX_cpd00002(b)','EX_cpd00006(b)','EX_cpd00005(b)','EX_cpd00010(b)','EX_cpd00003(b)','EX_cpd00012(b)','EX_cpd00018(b)','EX_cpd00001(b)','EX_cpd00046(b)','EX_cpd00096(b)','EX_cpd00254(b)','EX_cpd00052(b)','EX_cpd00038(b)','EX_cpd00031(b)','EX_cpd11493(b)','EX_cpd00126(b)','EX_cpd10516(b)','EX_cpd00205(b)','EX_cpd11463(b)','EX_cpd15499(b)','EX_cpd00063(b)','EX_cpd11462(b)','EX_cpd11461(b)','EX_cpd15664(b)','EX_cpd00201(b)','EX_cpd15800(b)'};
%biomassRxns = {'rxnBSbiomass'};
%biomassRxns = {'rxnBSbiomass_f_2'}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `listings` has an option for that: `breaklines=true`.

Comment: You may also want to have a look to the package [matlab-prettifier](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier).

Comment: @Johannes_B This destroys all the colour formatting, which I'd like to keep and don't have time to reinstate using 'mycolor' type commands.

Comment: @HarishKumar - this doesn't break the long arrays, it now just has          long_list = ...       {'item1','item2','item3', etc   until it reaches the end of the page and carries on, rather than splitting the array onto seperate lines!

Comment: Can you show your matlab code?

Comment: @HarishKumar the problematic code has been included above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\usepackage[numbered,breaklines=true]{mcode}` splits the long arrays properly, and is the solution I was looking for.